# Tailwind css classes issue in Creative Tim Notus react template

Tags: reactjs, responsive, tailwind-css

I am using [Notus react](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/notus-react) template.

I am trying to give different text size for different screens, but its not working. On medium screens, text size is also "text-2xs".

Tailwind "grid" classes are also not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all `text-2xs` is not any default tailwind class, so it will not work.

Seondaly if you want to have different font size for different screens, you can do so by adding this in the className.

```
text-base md:text-md lg:text-lg xl:text-xl
```

This will have text-base for screens < `md` breakpoint, `text-md` for screen  from `md` to `lg` breakpoint and so on.

For more info, refer [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design)

Comment: I am using https://www.creative-tim.com/product/notus-react template from Creative-tim.

I am trying to use tailwind grid classes but no effect. What could be the issue ?

<div class="grid grid-rows-3 grid-flow-col gap-4 m-10 bg-blue-100">
<div className="bg-green-300">01</div>
<div className="bg-green-300">02</div>
<div className="bg-green-300">03</div>
<div className="bg-green-300">04</div>
<div className="bg-green-300">05</div>
<div className="bg-green-300">06</div>
<div className="bg-green-300">07</div>
<div className="bg-green-300">08</div>
</div>